# ASP.Net Core, setting current culture based on subdomain?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to figure out how to set a sites Culture based on a subdomain in ASP.Net Core 1.1.

I have the following in my *Startup.cs*

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("fil-PH")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    if (UrlManagement.IsLocalizedUrl())
    {
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
        {
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = UrlManagement.GetCultureInfoFromUrl();
            ProviderCultureResult providerCultureResult = await new ProviderCultureResult(cultureInfo.Name);
            return providerCultureResult;
        }));
    }
});
```

It is complaining with this error at build time.

> 'ProviderCultureResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
>   and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'ProviderCultureResult' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

If I remove the await, then it complains that I should have an await.

If I remove the async, then it complains that it should be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I remove the await, then it complains that I should have an await.

No. It **warns** you that your `async` function does not have any `await` and will run synchronously. It's not an error. You can ignore this.

Comment: Thanks.  It is mildly annoying that the suggested method for inserting a RequestCultureProvider throws a warning.